# Why I am not able to fetch zebpay Api data?

Tags: php, api, curl, file-get-contents

I am using these code to fetch zebpay api data.
From this API URL - https://www.zebapi.com/api/v1/market/ticker/btc/inr

```
    function get_api($url){
        if(!empty($url)){
$api_url=$url;
if (@$_GET['curl']=="yes") {
  return(header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'));
} else {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$parsed_json = curl_exec($ch);
$parsed_json = json_decode($parsed_json);
return($parsed_json);
curl_close($ch);
    }
  }
}
$api= get_api('https://www.zebapi.com/api/v1/market/ticker/btc/inr');
echo $api->buy;
```

I have also try file_get_contents but same problem. I have face this issue in 2 more api's. 
Note: Once i get the data and use it correctly but today this is not working again.

Comment: use curl_error and curl_no to check what errors you got before close it.

Comment: Why are you using curl? You want to get prices with API. Thats the goal?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay How can i get price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call it directly by curl,

```
<?php

$getCurrency = "inr";
$displayArrayOutput = true;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.zebapi.com/api/v1/market/ticker/btc/inr",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    if($displayArrayOutput){
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($response);
    }
    else{
        header("Content-type:application/json");
        echo $response;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks @manish1706 - checking this in my site. Let me know if they can block my server ip is i try more and more

Comment: So if OP will add the extra curl options you have added to his code, will it work? Can you tell me what was the key thing which is missing in the OP's codE?

Comment: Also i can't get data from this url using your code- https://www.unocoin.com/trade?all